# Factorio analysis: data munging

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, scipy

[This project](https://github.com/reinderien/factorio/tree/462370a728defc4427d437be82adca3ac0e1f6c0) is... a little ridiculous. It's working, but it's a complete mess.

Data about Factorio's game economy are pulled from the wiki via the MediaWiki API, scrubbed, preprocessed, and thrown into Scipy for linear programming analysis using the MOSEK interior point method.

The pull script only depends on `requests`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json, lzma, re
from os.path import getsize
from requests import Session
from sys import stdout

session = Session()


def get_mediawiki(content=False, progress=None, **kwargs):
    """
    https://stable.wiki.factorio.com is an instance of MediaWiki.
    The API endpoint is
    https://stable.wiki.factorio.com/api.php
    """
    params = {'action': 'query',
              'format': 'json',
              **kwargs}
    if content:
        params.update({'prop': 'revisions',
                       'rvprop': 'content'})
    so_far = 0
    while True:
        resp = session.get('https://stable.wiki.factorio.com/api.php',
                           params=params)
        resp.raise_for_status()

        doc = resp.json()
        pages = doc['query']['pages'].values()
        if content:
            full_pages = tuple(p for p in pages if 'revisions' in p)
            if progress:
                so_far += len(full_pages)
                progress(so_far, len(pages))
            yield from full_pages
        else:
            yield from pages

        if 'batchcomplete' in doc:
            break
        params.update(doc['continue'])


def get_category(name, content=False, progress=None, **kwargs):
    return get_mediawiki(content=content, progress=progress,
                         generator='categorymembers',
                         gcmtitle=f'Category:{name}',
                         gcmtype='page',
                         gcmlimit=500,
                         **kwargs)


def get_archived_titles():
    return get_category('Archived')


def get_infoboxes(progress):
    return get_category('Infobox_page', content=True, progress=progress)


def get_inter_tables(titles, progress):
    return get_mediawiki(content=True, progress=progress,
                         titles='|'.join(titles))


line_re = re.compile(r'\n\s*\|')
var_re = re.compile(
    r'^\s*'
    r'(\S+)'
    r'\s*=\s*'
    r'(.+?)'
    r'\s*$')


def parse_infobox(page):
    """
    Example:

    {{Infobox
    |map-color = 006090
    |prototype-type = mining-drill
    |internal-name = burner-mining-drill
    |expensive-total-raw = Time, 8 + Iron plate, 30 + Stone, 10
    |expensive-recipe = Time, 4 + Iron gear wheel, 6 + Iron plate, 6 + Stone furnace, 2
    |category = Production
    |image=Burner-Mining-Drill-Example
    |health = 150
    |stack-size=50
    |dimensions=2×2
    |energy=300 {{Translation|kW}} burner
    |mining-power=2.5
    |mining-speed=0.35
    |mining-area=2×2
    |pollution=10
    |valid-fuel = Wood + Raw wood + Wooden chest + Coal + Solid fuel + Small electric pole + Rocket fuel + Nuclear fuel
    |recipe = Time, 2 + Iron gear wheel, 3 + Iron plate, 3 + Stone furnace, 1
    |total-raw = Time, 4 + Iron plate, 9 + Stone, 5
    |producers=Manual + Assembling machine 2 + Assembling machine 3
    }}<noinclude>
    [[Category:Infobox page]]
    </noinclude>

    Splitting on newline isn't a great idea, because
    https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Named_parameters
    shows that only the pipe is mandatory as a separator. However, only
    splitting on pipe is worse, because there are pipes on the inside of links.
    """

    content = page['revisions'][0]['*']
    entries = (
        var_re.match(e)
        for e in line_re.split(
            content.split('{{', maxsplit=1)[1]
            .rsplit('}}', maxsplit=1)[0]
        )
    )
    title = page['title'].split(':', maxsplit=1)[1]
    d = {'pageid': page['pageid'],
         'title': title}
    d.update(dict(e.groups() for e in entries if e))
    return d


part_tok = r'\s*([^|{}]*?)'
border_tok = r'\s*\|'
row_image_re = re.compile(
    r'\{\{\s*'
    r'(?P<type>\w+)'
    f'{border_tok}'
    f'{part_tok}'
    r'(?:'
       f'{border_tok}'    
       f'{part_tok}'
    r')?'
    r'(?:'
       f'{border_tok}'
       r'[^{}]*'
    r')?'
    r'\}\}\s*'
    r'(?P<sep>'
      r'(?:'
        r'\|\||\+|→'
      r')?'
    r')',
)


def iter_cells(row):
    """
    e.g.
    | {{Icon|Solid fuel from light oil||}}
    || {{icon|Light oil|10}} + {{icon|time|3}}
    || {{icon|Solid fuel|1}}
    or
    | {{Imagelink|Oil refinery}}
    || {{Imagelink|Basic oil processing}}
    || {{Icon|Crude oil|100}} + {{icon|Time|5}}
    → {{Icon|Heavy oil|30}} + ({{Icon|Light oil|30}} {{Icon|Petroleum gas|40}})
    """

    cell = []
    for m in row_image_re.finditer(row):
        if m.group('sep') == '||':
            cell.append(m.groups()[:-1])
            yield cell
            cell = []
        else:
            cell.append(m.groups())
    if cell:
        yield cell


def parse_inter_table(page):
    """
    Example:

    {| class="wikitable"
    ! Building !! Process !! Results
    |-
    | {{Imagelink|Oil refinery}} || {{Imagelink|Basic oil processing}} || {{Icon|Crude oil|100}} + {{icon|Time|5}} → {{Icon|Heavy oil|30}} + ({{Icon|Light oil|30}} {{Icon|Petroleum gas|40}})
    |-
    | {{Imagelink|Oil refinery}} || {{Imagelink|Advanced oil processing}} || {{Icon|Crude oil|100}} + {{icon|Water|50}} + {{icon|Time|5}} → {{Icon|Heavy oil|10}} + ({{Icon|Light oil|45}} {{Icon|Petroleum gas|55}})
    |-
    | {{Imagelink|Oil refinery}} || {{imagelink|Coal liquefaction}} || {{icon|Coal|10}} + {{Icon|Heavy oil|25}} + {{icon|Steam|50}} + {{icon|Time|5}} → {{Icon|Heavy oil|35}} + ({{Icon|Light oil|15}} + {{Icon|Petroleum gas|20}})
    |}

    or

    {| class="wikitable"
    ! Process !! Input !! Output
    |-
    | {{Icon|Solid fuel from heavy oil||}} || {{icon|Heavy oil|20}} + {{icon|time|3}} || {{icon|Solid fuel|1}}
    |-
    | {{Icon|Solid fuel from light oil||}} || {{icon|Light oil|10}} + {{icon|time|3}} || {{icon|Solid fuel|1}}
    |-
    | {{Icon|Solid fuel from petroleum gas||}} || {{icon|Petroleum gas|20}} + {{icon|time|3}} || {{icon|Solid fuel|1}}
    |-
    |}
    """
    title = page['title']
    content = page['revisions'][0]['*']
    if '{|' not in content:
        return title, {}

    rows = []
    body = (content
            .replace('\n', '')
            .split('{|', maxsplit=1)[1]
            .rsplit('|}', maxsplit=1)[0])
    row_strings = body.split('|-')
    heads = tuple(h.strip().lower() for h in row_strings[0]
                  .split('!', maxsplit=1)[1]
                  .split('!!'))

    for line in row_strings[1:]:
        inputs = {}
        outputs = {}
        row = {'inputs': inputs, 'outputs': outputs}
        for head, parts in zip(heads, iter_cells(line)):
            if head in ('process', 'building'):
                row[head.lower()] = parts[0][1]
                continue
            elif head not in ('input', 'output', 'results'):
                if head == '':
                    return title, {}  # Space science pack edge case
                raise ValueError(f'Unrecognized head {head}')

            if 'input' in head:
                side = inputs
            elif 'output' in head:
                side = outputs
            else:
                side = inputs
                if 'results' not in head:
                    raise ValueError(f'Unexpected heading {head}')
            for part in parts:
                res_type = part[0].lower()
                if res_type != 'icon':
                    raise ValueError(f'Unexpected resource type {res_type}')
                side[part[1]] = int(part[2])
                if 'results' in head and len(part) == 4 and part[-1] == '→':
                    side = outputs

        if inputs or outputs:
            rows.append(row)

    return title, {'recipes': rows}


def inter_needed(items):
    return (i['title'] for i in items if
            not i['archived']
            and i.get('category') == 'Intermediate products'
            and not ('cost' in i or 'recipe' in i))


def save(fn, recipes):
    with lzma.open(fn, 'wt') as f:
        json.dump(recipes, f, indent=4)


def main():
    def progress(so_far, total):
        print(f'{so_far}/{total} {so_far/total:.0%}', end='\r')
        stdout.flush()

    print('Getting archived items... ', end='')
    archived_titles = {p['title'] for p in get_archived_titles()}
    print(len(archived_titles))

    print('Getting item content...')
    items = tuple(parse_infobox(p) for p in get_infoboxes(progress))
    items_by_name = {i['title']: i for i in items}
    for item in items:
        item['archived'] = item['title'] in archived_titles

    print('\nFilling in intermediate products...')
    inter_tables = get_inter_tables(inter_needed(items), progress)
    used = 0
    for table_page in inter_tables:
        try:
            title, recipes = parse_inter_table(table_page)
            if recipes:
                used += 1
                items_by_name[title].update(recipes)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'\nWarning: {table_page["title"]} failed to parse - {e}')
    print(f'\n{used} intermediate tables used.')

    fn = 'items.json.xz'
    print(f'Saving to {fn}... ', end='')
    save(fn, items_by_name)
    print(f'{getsize(fn)//1024} kiB')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You need to run it before any of the next steps. After the data are pulled, run the preprocessing script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json, lzma, re
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from os.path import getsize
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix, save_npz
from sys import stdout
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Set, Sequence


power_re = re.compile(r'([0-9.]+) .*([kMG])[WJ]')

si_facs = {
    c: 10**(3*i) for i, c in enumerate(('', 'k', 'M', 'G'))
}


class Item:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = data
        (
            self.archived,
            self.cost,
            self.cost_multiplier,
            self.crafting_speed,
            self.dimensions,
            self.energy,
            self.fluid_consumption,
            self.fuel_value,
            self.mining_hardness,
            self.mining_power,
            self.mining_speed,
            self.mining_time,
            self.pollution,
            self.power_output,
            self.producers,
            self.prototype_type,
            self.recipe,
            self.recipes,
            self.title,
            self.valid_fuel
        ) = (None,)*20
        self.__dict__.update({k.replace('-', '_'): v
                              for k, v in data.items()})
        self.fill_gaps()

    def fill_gaps(self):
        if self.prototype_type == 'technology':
            self.producers = 'Lab'
        elif self.title in ('Flamethrower turret', 'Gun turret',
                            'Laser turret'):
            self.producers = 'Assembling machine + manual'
        elif self.title == 'Space science pack':
            self.recipe = 'Time, 41.25 + Rocket part, 100 = ' \
                          'Space science pack, 1000'
        elif self.title == 'Steam':
            ex_rate = 10e6 * 60 / 5.82e6
            self.recipes = (
                {
                    'process': 'Steam165 (Boiler)',
                    'building': 'Boiler',
                    'inputs': {
                        'Water': 60,
                        'Time': 1
                    },
                    'outputs': {
                        'Steam165': 60
                    }
                },
                {
                    'process': 'Steam500 (Heat exchanger)',
                    'building': 'Heat exchanger',
                    'inputs': {
                        'Water': ex_rate,
                        'Time': 1
                    },
                    'outputs': {
                        'Steam500': ex_rate
                    }
                }
            )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    @property
    def keep(self) -> bool:
        return (
            (not self.archived) and
            (self.title not in {'Rock', 'Tree'}) and
            (
                any(self.data.get(k) for k in ('cost', 'recipe', 'recipes'))
                or 'mining-hardness' in self.data
                or self.title in {'Crude oil',
                                  'Water',
                                  'Space science pack',
                                  'Steam'}
            )
        )

    def get_recipes(self) -> Iterable:
        if self.recipes:
            for rates in self.recipes:
                fac = RecipeFactory(self, rates=rates)
                yield from fac.make()
        else:
            fac = RecipeFactory(self)
            yield from fac.make()

    def mine_rate(self, mining_hardness: float, mining_time: float) -> float:
        return (
                (float(self.mining_power) - mining_hardness)
                * float(self.mining_speed) / mining_time
        )


all_items: Dict[str, Item] = None


class ManualMiner:
    def __init__(self, tool: Item):
        self.tool = tool
        self.title = f'Manual with {tool}'
        self.pollution = 0
        self.dimensions = '0×0'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def mine_rate(self, mining_hardness: float, mining_time: float) -> float:
        return (
                0.6 * (float(self.tool.mining_power) - mining_hardness)
                / mining_time
        )


class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, resource: str, producer: Item, rates: dict,
                 title: str = None):
        self.resource = resource
        if title:
            self.title = title
        else:
            self.title = f'{resource} ({producer})'

        self.rates = dict(rates)
        self.producer = producer
        self.multiply_producer(producer)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def multiply_producer(self, prod: Item):
        if prod.title in {'Boiler', 'Heat exchanger', 'Solar panel',
                          'Steam engine', 'Steam turbine'}:
            pass  # no crafting rate modifier
        elif prod.title == 'Nuclear reactor':
            self.rates['Heat'] = parse_power(prod.energy)
        else:
            rate = float(prod.crafting_speed)
            for k in self.rates:
                self.rates[k] *= rate


class MiningRecipe(Recipe):
    def __init__(self, resource: str, producer: Item, rates: dict,
                 mining_hardness: float, mining_time: float, title: str = ''):
        self.mining_hardness, self.mining_time = mining_hardness, mining_time
        super().__init__(resource, producer, rates, title)

    def multiply_producer(self, miner: Item):
        self.rates[self.resource] = self.producer.mine_rate(
            self.mining_hardness, self.mining_time
        )
        if self.resource == 'Uranium ore':
            self.rates['Sulphuric acid'] = -self.rates[self.resource]


class TechRecipe(Recipe):
    def __init__(self, resource: str, producer: Item, rates: dict,
                 cost_multiplier: float, title: str = ''):
        self.cost_multiplier = cost_multiplier
        super().__init__(resource, producer, rates, title)

    def multiply_producer(self, lab: Item):
        self.rates[self.resource] /= self.cost_multiplier


class FluidRecipe(Recipe):
    # Pumpjacks, offshore pumps
    def multiply_producer(self, producer: Item):
        if producer.title == 'Pumpjack':
            yield_factor = 1.00  # Assumed
            rate = 10*yield_factor
        elif producer.title == 'Offshore pump':
            rate = 1200
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()
        self.rates[self.resource] = rate


class RecipeFactory:
    def __init__(self, resource: Item, rates: dict = None):
        self.resource = resource
        self.producers = ()
        if rates:
            self.producers, self.title, self.rates = self.intermediate(rates)
        else:
            self.title = None
            needs_producers = False
            recipe = resource.recipe or resource.cost
            if recipe:
                self.rates = self.parse_recipe(recipe)
                if resource.prototype_type == 'technology':
                    self.producers = (all_items['lab'],)
                else:
                    needs_producers = True
            else:
                if resource.mining_time or \
                        resource.title in {'Crude oil', 'Water'}:
                    self.rates = {}
                    if resource.title != 'Raw wood':
                        needs_producers = True
                else:
                    raise NotImplementedError()
            if needs_producers:
                self.producers = tuple(parse_producers(resource.producers))

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def intermediate(self, rates) -> (Iterable[Item], str, dict):
        building = rates.get('building')
        if building:
            producers = (all_items[building.lower()],)
        else:
            producers = parse_producers(self.resource.producers)
        title = rates['process']
        sane_rates = self.calc_recipe(rates['inputs'], rates['outputs'])
        return producers, title, sane_rates

    @staticmethod
    def parse_side(s: str) -> Dict[str, float]:
        out = {}
        for pair in s.split('+'):
            k, v = pair.split(',')
            out[k.strip()] = float(v.strip())
        return out

    @staticmethod
    def calc_recipe(inputs: Dict[str, float],
                    outputs: Dict[str, float]) -> Dict[str, float]:
        rates = defaultdict(float, outputs)
        if 'time' in inputs:
            k = 'time'
        else:
            k = 'Time'
        t = inputs.pop(k)
        for k in rates:
            rates[k] /= t
        for k, v in inputs.items():
            rates[k] -= v / t
        return rates

    def parse_recipe(self, recipe: str) -> Dict[str, float]:
        if '=' in recipe:
            inputs, outputs = recipe.split('=')
            outputs = self.parse_side(outputs)
        else:
            inputs = recipe
            outputs = {self.resource.title: 1}

        return self.calc_recipe(self.parse_side(inputs), outputs)

    def produce(self, cls, producer, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('title', self.title)
        recipe = cls(self.resource.title, producer, self.rates, **kwargs)
        if producer.pollution:
            recipe.rates['Pollution'] = float(producer.pollution)

        dims = tuple(float(x) for x in producer.dimensions.split('×'))
        recipe.rates['Area'] = dims[0] * dims[1]

        return recipe

    def for_energy(self, cls, **kwargs) -> Iterable[Recipe]:
        for producer in self.producers:
            energy = -parse_power(producer.energy)

            if 'electric' in producer.energy:
                recipe = self.produce(cls, producer, **kwargs)
                recipe.rates['Energy'] = energy
                yield recipe

            elif 'heat' in producer.energy:
                recipe = self.produce(cls, producer, **kwargs)
                recipe.rates['Heat'] = energy
                yield recipe

            elif 'burner' in producer.energy:
                for fuel_name in producer.valid_fuel.split('+'):
                    fuel_name = fuel_name.strip().lower()
                    fuel = all_items[fuel_name]
                    fuel_value = parse_power(fuel.fuel_value)
                    new_kwargs = dict(kwargs)
                    if self.title:
                        title = self.title
                    else:
                        title = f'{self.resource} ({producer})'
                    new_kwargs['title'] = f'{title} fueled by {fuel_name}'

                    recipe = self.produce(cls, producer, **new_kwargs)
                    recipe.rates[fuel.title] = energy / fuel_value
                    yield recipe
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError()

    tree_re = re.compile(r'(\d+) .*?\|([^}|]+)\}')

    def wood_mining(self) -> Iterable[MiningRecipe]:
        miners = tuple(
            ManualMiner(tool)
            for tool in all_items.values()
            if tool.prototype_type == 'mining-tool'
        )
        for m in self.tree_re.finditer(self.resource.mining_time):
            mining_time, source = int(m[1]), m[2]
            for miner in miners:
                yield self.produce(
                    MiningRecipe, miner,
                    mining_hardness=float(self.resource.mining_hardness),
                    mining_time=mining_time,
                    title=f'{self.resource} ({miner} from {source})')

    def make(self) -> Iterable[Recipe]:
        if self.rates:
            if self.resource.prototype_type == 'technology':
                yield self.produce(
                    TechRecipe, self.producers[0],
                    cost_multiplier=float(self.resource.cost_multiplier))
            elif self.resource.title == 'Energy':
                yield self.produce(Recipe, self.producers[0])
            else:
                yield from self.for_energy(Recipe)
        elif self.resource.title == 'Raw wood':
            yield from self.wood_mining()
        elif self.resource.mining_time:
            yield from self.for_energy(
                MiningRecipe,
                mining_hardness=float(self.resource.mining_hardness),
                mining_time=float(self.resource.mining_time))
        elif self.resource.title == 'Crude oil':
            yield from self.for_energy(FluidRecipe)
        elif self.resource.title == 'Water':
            yield self.produce(FluidRecipe, self.producers[0])
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()


def parse_power(s: str) -> float:
    m = power_re.search(s)
    return float(m[1]) * si_facs[m[2]]


def items_of_type(t: str) -> Iterable[Item]:
    return (i for i in all_items.values()
            if i.prototype_type == t)


barrel_re = re.compile(r'empty .+ barrel')


def parse_producers(s: str) -> Iterable[Item]:
    for p in s.split('+'):
        p = p.strip().lower()
        if p == 'furnace':
            yield from items_of_type('furnace')
        elif p == 'assembling machine':
            yield from (all_items[f'assembling machine {i}']
                        for i in range(1, 4))
        elif p == 'mining drill':
            yield from (all_items[f'{t} mining drill']
                        for t in ('burner', 'electric'))
        elif p == 'manual' or barrel_re.match(p):
            continue
        else:
            yield all_items[p]


def trim(items: dict):
    to_delete = tuple(k for k, v in items.items() if not v.keep)
    print(f'Dropping {len(to_delete)} items...')
    for k in to_delete:
        del items[k]


def energy_data() -> dict:
    solar_ave = parse_power(next(
        s for s in all_items['solar panel'].power_output.split('<br/>')
        if 'average' in s))

    eng = all_items['steam engine']
    eng_rate = float(eng.fluid_consumption
                     .split('/')[0])
    eng_power = parse_power(eng.power_output)

    turbine = all_items['steam turbine']
    turbine_rate = float(turbine.fluid_consumption
                         .split('/')[0])
    turbine_power_500 = 5.82e6  # ignore non-precise data and use this instead
    turbine_power_165 = 1.8e6   # from wiki page body

    return {
        'title': 'Energy',
        'recipes': (
            {
                'building': 'Solar panel',
                'process': 'Energy (Solar panel)',
                'inputs': {
                    'Time': 1
                },
                'outputs': {
                    'Energy': solar_ave
                }
            },
            {
                'building': 'Steam engine',
                'process': 'Energy (Steam engine)',
                'inputs': {
                    'Time': 1,
                    'Steam165': eng_rate
                },
                'outputs': {
                    'Energy': eng_power
                }
            },
            {
                'building': 'Steam turbine',
                'process': 'Energy (Steam turbine @ 165C)',
                'inputs': {
                    'Time': 1,
                    'Steam165': turbine_rate
                },
                'outputs': {
                    'Energy': turbine_power_165
                }
            },
            {
                'building': 'Steam turbine',
                'process': 'Energy (Steam turbine @ 500C)',
                'inputs': {
                    'Time': 1,
                    'Steam500': turbine_rate
                },
                'outputs': {
                    'Energy': turbine_power_500
                }
            }
        )
    }


def load(fn: str):
    with lzma.open(fn) as f:
        global all_items
        all_items = {k.lower(): Item(d) for k, d in json.load(f).items()}
    all_items['energy'] = Item(energy_data())


def get_recipes() -> (Dict[str, Recipe], Set[str]):
    recipes = {}
    resources = set()
    for item in all_items.values():
        item_recipes = tuple(item.get_recipes())
        recipes.update({i.title: i for i in item_recipes})
        for recipe in item_recipes:
            resources.update(recipe.rates.keys())

    return recipes, resources


def field_size(names: Iterable) -> int:
    return max(len(str(o)) for o in names)


def write_csv_for_r(recipes: Sequence[Recipe], resources: Sequence[str],
                    fn: str):
    # Recipes going down, resources going right

    rec_width = field_size(recipes)
    float_width = 15
    col_format = f'{{:{float_width+8}}}'
    rec_format = '\n{:' + str(rec_width+1) + '}'

    with lzma.open(fn, 'wt') as f:
        f.write(' '*(rec_width+1))
        for res in resources:
            f.write(col_format.format(f'{res},'))

        for rec in recipes:
            f.write(rec_format.format(f'{rec},'))
            for res in resources:
                x = rec.rates.get(res, 0)
                col_format = f'{{:+{len(res)}.{float_width}e}},'
                f.write(col_format.format(x))


def write_for_numpy(recipes: Sequence[Recipe], resources: Sequence[str],
                    meta_fn: str, npz_fn: str):
    rec_names = [r.title for r in recipes]
    w_rec = max(len(r) for r in rec_names)
    recipe_names = np.array(rec_names, copy=False, dtype=f'U{w_rec}')

    w_res = max(len(r) for r in resources)
    resource_names = np.array(resources, copy=False, dtype=f'U{w_res}')

    np.savez_compressed(meta_fn, recipe_names=recipe_names, resource_names=resource_names)

    rec_mat = lil_matrix((len(resources), len(recipes)))
    for j, rec in enumerate(recipes):
        for res, q in rec.rates.items():
            i = resources.index(res)
            rec_mat[i, j] = q
    save_npz(npz_fn, rec_mat.tocsr())


def file_banner(fn):
    print(f'{fn} {getsize(fn)//1024} kiB')


def main():
    fn = 'items.json.xz'
    print(f'Loading {fn}... ', end='')
    load(fn)
    print(f'{len(all_items)} items')

    trim(all_items)

    print('Calculating recipes... ', end='')
    recipes, resources = get_recipes()
    print(f'{len(recipes)} recipes, {len(resources)} resources')

    resources = sorted(resources)
    recipes = sorted(recipes.values(), key=lambda i: i.title)

    print('Saving files for numpy...')
    meta_fn, npz_fn = 'recipe-names.npz', 'recipes.npz'
    write_for_numpy(recipes, resources, meta_fn, npz_fn)
    file_banner(meta_fn)
    file_banner(npz_fn)

    fn = 'recipes.csv.xz'
    print(f'Saving recipes for use by R...')
    stdout.flush()
    write_csv_for_r(recipes, resources, fn)
    file_banner(fn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That's followed by an analysis script that I won't post here, to constrain the scope of this first review.

`items.json.xz` is somewhat large; an excerpt is:

```
{
    "Advanced circuit": {
        "pageid": 38306,
        "title": "Advanced circuit",
        "prototype-type": "item",
        "internal-name": "advanced-circuit",
        "expensive-total-raw": "Time, 14 + Copper plate, 14 + Iron plate, 4 + Plastic bar, 4",
        "expensive-recipe": "Time, 6 + Copper cable, 8 + Electronic circuit, 2 + Plastic bar, 4",
        "category": "Intermediate products",
        "stack-size": "200",
        "recipe": "Time, 6 + Copper cable, 4 + Electronic circuit, 2 + Plastic bar, 2",
        "total-raw": "Time, 9.5 + Copper plate, 5 + Iron plate, 2 + Plastic bar, 2",
        "required-technologies": "Advanced electronics",
        "producers": "Manual + Assembling machine 2+Assembling machine 3",
        "consumers": "Artillery turret + Artillery wagon + Beacon + Centrifuge + Distractor capsule + Efficiency module + Efficiency module 2 + Efficiency module 3 + Electric furnace + Energy shield + Express splitter + Active provider chest + Buffer chest + Passive provider chest + Requester chest + Storage chest + Logistic robot + Modular armor + Nightvision + Nuclear reactor + Personal roboport + Processing unit + Productivity module + Productivity module 2 + Productivity module 3 + Roboport + Science pack 3 + Portable solar panel + Speed module + Speed module 2 + Speed module 3 + Stack inserter + Substation + Tank",
        "archived": false
    },
    "Advanced oil processing (research)": {
        "pageid": 38335,
        "title": "Advanced oil processing (research)",
        "prototype-type": "technology",
        "internal-name": "advanced-oil-processing",
        "allows": "Coal liquefaction",
        "expensive-cost-multiplier": "300",
        "category": "Technology",
        "cost": "Time, 30 + Science pack 1, 1 + Science pack 2, 1 + Science pack 3, 1",
        "cost-multiplier": "75",
        "required-technologies": "Oil processing",
        "effects": "Advanced oil processing + Heavy oil cracking + Light oil cracking",
        "archived": false
    },
```

It's just as easy for you to generate it yourself. Similarly, here is an excerpt of `recipes.csv.xz`:

```
                                                                        Accumulator,           Active provider chest, Advanced circuit,      Advanced electronics (research),Advanced electronics 2 (research),Advanced material processing (research),Advanced material processing 2 (research),Advanced oil processing (research),Area,                  Arithmetic combinator, Artillery (research),  Artillery shell,       Artillery shell range (research),Artillery shell shooting speed (research),Artillery targeting remote,Artillery turret,      Artillery wagon,       Assembling machine 1,  Assembling machine 2,  Assembling machine 3,  Atomic bomb,           Atomic bomb (research),Auto character logistic trash slots (research),Automated rail transportation (research),Automation (research), Automation 2 (research),Automation 3 (research),Automobilism (research),Battery,               Battery (research),    Battery MK1,           Battery MK2 equipment (research),Battery equipment (research),Beacon,                Big electric pole,     Boiler,                Braking force (research),Buffer chest,          Bullet damage (research),Bullet shooting speed (research),Burner inserter,       Burner mining drill,   Cannon shell,          Cannon shell damage (research),Cannon shell shooting speed (research),Car,                   Cargo wagon,           Centrifuge,            Character logistic slots (research),Character logistic trash slots (research),Chemical plant,        Circuit network (research),Cliff explosives,      Cliff explosives (research),Cluster grenade,       Coal,                  Coal liquefaction (research),Combat robot damage (research),Combat robotics (research),Combat robotics 2 (research),Combat robotics 3 (research),Combat shotgun,        Concrete,              Concrete (research),   Constant combinator,   Construction robot,    Construction robotics (research),Copper cable,          Copper ore,            Copper plate,          Crude oil,             Decider combinator,    Defender capsule,      Destroyer capsule,     Discharge defense,     Discharge defense (research),Discharge defense remote,Distractor capsule,    Effect transmission (research),Efficiency module,     Efficiency module (research),Efficiency module 2,   Efficiency module 2 (research),Efficiency module 3,   Efficiency module 3 (research),Electric energy accumulators (research),Electric energy distribution 1 (research),Electric energy distribution 2 (research),Electric engine (research),Electric engine unit,  Electric furnace,      Electric mining drill, Electronic circuit,    Electronics (research),Empty barrel,          Energy,                Energy shield,         Energy shield MK2,     Energy shield MK2 equipment (research),Energy shield equipment (research),Engine (research),     Engine unit,           Exoskeleton,           Exoskeleton equipment (research),Explosive cannon shell,Explosive rocket,      Explosive rocketry (research),Explosive uranium cannon shell,Explosives,            Explosives (research), Express splitter,      Express transport belt,Express underground belt,Fast inserter,         Fast splitter,         Fast transport belt,   Fast underground belt, Filter inserter,       Firearm magazine,      Flamethrower,          Flamethrower (research),Flamethrower ammo,     Flamethrower damage (research),Flamethrower turret,   Flammables (research), Flight (research),     Fluid handling (research),Fluid wagon,           Fluid wagon (research),Flying robot frame,    Follower robot count (research),Gate,                  Gates (research),      Green wire,            Grenade,               Grenade damage (research),Gun turret,            Gun turret damage (research),Hazard concrete,       Heat,                  Heat exchanger,        Heat pipe,             Heavy armor,           Heavy armor (research),Heavy oil,             High tech science pack,Inserter,              Inserter capacity bonus (research),Iron axe,              Iron chest,            Iron gear wheel,       Iron ore,              Iron plate,            Iron stick,            Kovarex enrichment process (research),Lab,                   Lab research speed (research),Lamp,                  Land mine,             Landfill,              Landfill (research),   Landmines (research),  Laser (research),      Laser turret,          Laser turret damage (research),Laser turret shooting speed (research),Laser turrets (research),Light armor,           Light oil,             Locomotive,            Logistic robot,        Logistic robotics (research),Logistic system (research),Logistics (research),  Logistics 2 (research),Logistics 3 (research),Long handed inserter,  Low density structure, Lubricant,             Medium electric pole,  Military (research),   Military 2 (research), Military 3 (research), Military 4 (research), Military science pack, Mining productivity (research),Modular armor,         Modular armor (research),Modules (research),    Nightvision,           Nightvision equipment (research),Nuclear fuel,          Nuclear fuel reprocessing (research),Nuclear power (research),Nuclear reactor,       Offshore pump,         Oil processing (research),Oil refinery,          Optics (research),     Passive provider chest,Personal battery,      Personal battery MK2,  Personal laser defense,Personal laser defense (research),Personal roboport,     Personal roboport (research),Personal roboport 2 (research),Personal roboport MK2, Petroleum gas,         Piercing rounds magazine,Piercing shotgun shells,Pipe,                  Pipe to ground,        Pistol,                Plastic bar,           Plastics (research),   Poison capsule,        Pollution,             Portable fusion reactor,Portable fusion reactor (research),Portable solar panel,  Portable solar panel (research),Power armor,           Power armor (research),Power armor 2 (research),Power armor MK2,       Power switch,          Processing unit,       Production science pack,Productivity module,   Productivity module (research),Productivity module 2, Productivity module 2 (research),Productivity module 3, Productivity module 3 (research),Programmable speaker,  Pump,                  Pumpjack,              Radar,                 Rail,                  Rail chain signal,     Rail signal,           Rail signals (research),Railway (research),    Raw wood,              Red wire,              Refined concrete,      Refined hazard concrete,Repair pack,           Requester chest,       Roboport,              Robotics (research),   Rocket,                Rocket control unit,   Rocket damage (research),Rocket fuel,           Rocket launcher,       Rocket part,           Rocket shooting speed (research),Rocket silo,           Rocket silo (research),Rocketry (research),   Satellite,             Science pack 1,        Science pack 2,        Science pack 3,        Shotgun,               Shotgun shell damage (research),Shotgun shell shooting speed (research),Shotgun shells,        Slowdown capsule,      Small electric pole,   Solar energy (research),Solar panel,           Solid fuel,            Space science pack,    Speed module,          Speed module (research),Speed module 2,        Speed module 2 (research),Speed module 3,        Speed module 3 (research),Splitter,              Stack filter inserter, Stack inserter,        Stack inserter (research),Steam,                 Steam engine,          Steam turbine,         Steam165,              Steam500,              Steel axe,             Steel chest,           Steel furnace,         Steel plate,           Steel processing (research),Stone,                 Stone brick,           Stone furnace,         Stone wall,            Stone walls (research),Storage chest,         Storage tank,          Submachine gun,        Substation,            Sulfur,                Sulfur processing (research),Sulfuric acid,         Sulphuric acid,        Tank,                  Tanks (research),      Toolbelt (research),   Train stop,            Transport belt,        Turrets (research),    Underground belt,      Uranium ammo (research),Uranium cannon shell,  Uranium fuel cell,     Uranium ore,           Uranium rounds magazine,Uranium-235,           Uranium-238,           Used up uranium fuel cell,Water,                 Wood,                  Wooden chest,          Worker robot cargo size (research),Worker robot speed (research),
Accumulator (Assembling machine 1),                                     +5.000000000000000e-02,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,           +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+9.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,                        +0.000000000000000e+00,                  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,-2.500000000000000e-01,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,             +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,     +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,-9.000000000000000e+04,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,-1.000000000000000e-01,+0.000000000000000e+00,               +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,              +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,           +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+3.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,     +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,
Accumulator (Assembling machine 2),                                     +7.500000000000001e-02,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,           +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+9.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,                        +0.000000000000000e+00,                  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,-3.750000000000000e-01,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,             +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,     +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,                   +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,-1.500000000000000e+05,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,-1.500000000000000e-01,+0.000000000000000e+00,               +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,                +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,    +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,              +0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,           +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+2.400000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,        +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,  +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,          +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,         +0.000000000000000e+00,                 +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,     +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,      +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00, +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,   +0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,+0.000000000000000e+00,            +0.000000000000000e+00,       +0.000000000000000e+00,
```

The main thing that needs work is the recipe factory code. It sprinkles logic about item types where it doesn't belong, and that really needs to be improved. I have some ideas about how to do that, but I'd like to hear from the community (on that, and any other wrinkles you find).

Comment: All the data is in machine readable lua files - even version-tagged in the official repository: https://github.com/wube/factorio-data. There's also existing python tooling to read the lua https://github.com/jcranmer/factorio-tools (not sure what state that it is in).

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the output of this looks like?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Added, though it's more helpful to just run the scripts and get the full output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can simplify your 'verbose' multi-line regexes by using the [`re.X` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X).

  ```
  var_re = re.compile(r'''
      ^\s*
      (\S+)
      \s*=\s*
      (.+?)
      \s*$
  ''', re.X)
  ```
- > The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation. - [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

  ```
  if (resource.mining_time
          or resource.title in {'Crude oil', 'Water'}):
      ...
  ```

  Whilst it goes against the style in your code, I prefer the following:

  ```
  if (resource.mining_time
      or resource.title in {'Crude oil', 'Water'}
  ):
      ...
  ```